# Is $\mathbb{R}^{n} = \mathbb{Q}^{n}∪\mathbb{I}^{n}??$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $n=1$ the result follows but if we assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$ arbitrary what about for the case when $n = 2$ and take the point $a = (1, e)$.  $a \in \mathbb{Q}^{2}$ or $a \in \mathbb{I}^{2}$?

Comment: Are these vector spaces? $V^n \simeq V \oplus \dots \text{(\(n\) times)} \dots \oplus V$, for any $k$-vector space $V$, and the direct sum is commutative up to isomorphism.

Comment: Equal as what? If as sets, you should use the symbol $\cup$. If as vector spaces, this is false even for $n=1$. (I'm assuming $\mathbb I$ denotes the irrational numbers, which is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb R$)

Comment: $\mathbb{I}^{n}$ is not closed for addition (in particular....)

Comment: Guys, sorry by the misundertanding. I was thinking in sets and not vector spaces, and yes $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of irrational numbers. I will edit the title right now.

Comment: i just wanna know where are the point with rational and irrational coordinates like the point $a$.

Comment: In $\Bbb{Q\times I}$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes when $n=1$, but no otherwise. It seems like you are aware of the reason why. The element $(1,e)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is in neither $\mathbb Q^2$ nor $\mathbb I^2$. We can invent similar elements in $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $A=(B \cup C)$ with $B \cap C = \emptyset$ implies
$$
A^2 = (B \cup C) \times (B \cup C) = B^2 \cup (B\times C) \cup (C \times B) \cup C^2
$$

Comment: Much like $(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2$.